# Clicking an Input Button more than once in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, button, input, onclick

I'm building out a dice game using HTML5 and JavaScript.

I want a player to be able to select a dice with an onlclick. This will stop the dice from being rolled.  The player should be able to onclick the dice button again which will allow the dice to be rolled again.

I have played with the code and the first onclick works but the second onclick does not.

Is this a limitation of one onclick per input button or should I use another HTML tag other than input button?

I want the game to be played without reloading the screen.

### HTML5

```
<tr>
<th><input type="button" id="diceOne" onclick="selectDice(this.id,this.value)" value="0"></input></th>

<th><input type="button" id="diceTwo" onclick="selectDice(this.id,this.value)" value="1"></input></th>

<th><input type="button" id="diceThree" onclick="selectDice(this.id,this.value)" value="2"></input></th>

<th><input type="button" id="diceFour" onclick="selectDice(this.id,this.value)" value="3"></input></th>

<th><input type="button" id="diceFive" onclick="selectDice(this.id,this.value)" value="4"></input></th>
</tr>
```

### Javascript

```
function selectDice(diceName,diceValue){
if (diceArray[diceValue][1]=="y"){
    alert(diceArray[diceValue][1]);
    document.getElementById(diceName).value = "Die now selected";
    diceArray[diceValue][1]="n";
    alert(diceArray[diceValue][1]); 
} 
else {
    alert(diceArray[diceValue][1]); 
    document.getElementById(diceName).value = "Die not selected";
    diceArray[diceValue][1]="y";
    alert(diceArray[diceValue][1]); 
}

}
```

Comment: It's 2011! Why you're using inline onclick? poooof!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create variables for each one of those buttons and trigger them true/false for each click in your javascript as a condition and that should fix your second click ;)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might have a bug in your code. I think this is what is going on:

1. You click on the first die, which leads to a call to selectDice, passing in the id for diceName, and the value for diceValue; or "diceOne" and "0" respectively.
2. In whichever path of the if statement it follows, you do a document.getElementById(diceName), which is going to get the input element you clicked on (so in this case, the first input element), and changes the value to either "Die now selected" or "Die not selected". This is where everything goes wrong.
3. The next time you click on that die, it calls selectDice, and again passes in the id for diceName, and the value for diceValue...except this time, diceName is "diceOne" and diceValue is "Die now selected". Since you don't have a value for the index "Die now selected" in the diceArray object, everything goes downhill from here.

I'd suggest trying this code without the "document.getElementById(diceName).value = ..." lines and see if it works then. If you really need to change the input element's value in your onclick, then I'd suggest either not using an inline onclick, or pass in the literal value you want for diceName and diceValue like so:

```
<input type="button" id="diceOne" onclick="selectDice('diceOne','0')" value="0"></input>
```